# Get id from Entity record

Tags: haskell, haskell-persistent

I have an `Entity record`, specifically `Entity User` and I need to extract the Id which the User has in the database as an `Int`.

From reading the [docs](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-10.3/persistent-2.7.1/Database-Persist-Types.html#t:Entity) it seems `entityKey` would be useful here but I'm not quite sure how I would go about getting an `Int` out.

Comment: can you show us the definition of your data types and the context where you want to use this?

Comment: What persistent backend are you using? The definition of what a `Key` is depends on what kind of database we're talking about.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe It's all auto generated by Yesod.

Comment: Then show the corresponding lines in your config and where you use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a combination of `fromSqlKey` and `entityKey`. A sample program demonstrating it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack
     --resolver lts-9.0
     --install-ghc
     runghc
     --package persistent
     --package persistent-sqlite
     --package persistent-template
     --package mtl
-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies               #-}
import           Control.Monad.IO.Class  (liftIO, MonadIO)
import Control.Monad.Reader
import           Database.Persist
import           Database.Persist.Sqlite
import           Database.Persist.TH
import Data.Int

share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
Person
    name String
    age Int Maybe
    deriving Show
|]

insertPerson :: MonadIO m => ReaderT SqlBackend m (Key Person)
insertPerson =  insert $ Person "Michael" $ Just 26

main :: IO ()
main = runSqlite ":memory:" $ do
    runMigration migrateAll
    michaelId <- insertPerson
    (michael :: Entity Person) <- getJustEntity michaelId
    liftIO $ print $ (fromSqlKey . entityKey $ michael :: Int64)
```

And it's output:

```
~/g/scripts $ stack persist.hs
Migrating: CREATE TABLE "person"("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"name" VARCHAR NOT NULL,"age" INTEGER NULL)
1
```